# Get a Win32 program to request a debugger on startup?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, qt, winapi

We have a C++ Win32 application which spawns, using Qt's QProcess (undoubtedly a wrapper for CreateProcess()), a secondary 'slave' program.

Unfortunately, when debugging the system with Visual Studio 2008, the debugger does not automatically attach to the spawned process.

I know it's possible to programmatically trigger a debugger breakpoint with __debugbreak(), but is it possible for the slave program to throw up the 'Choose a Program to Debug This' window immediately on startup since at the moment we have to race to manually attach to the new process?

Comment: Try adding _asm int 3 at the start of the slave program. Compile with debug symbols and use Visual Studio 2008 as the JIT debugger.

Comment: @toto: That's the same as just calling DebugBreak(), basically.

Comment: You know the real tragedy is the OS level hooks are there - when a debugger creates a process it gets to specify flags that would let it automatically be notified as soon as a child process is launched.
10 years later, our dev environment still doesn't support them :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Image File Execution Options](http://blogs.msdn.com/greggm/archive/2005/02/21/377663.aspx).  You can specify the Visual Studio just-in-time debugger as the default debugger to attach to the process.

If you're into using the [command-line debuggers](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/DevTools/Debugging/default.mspx), you can use `ntsd -o` to automatically debug child processes as well.

Comment: Ahh fantastic, that's certainly helped - it's now throwing up an error box (Windows cannot find '<full-path-to-exe-file>'. Make sure you typed the name correctly blah blah) but I'm certainly on the right track now; many thanks.

Comment: Yeah, you want to replace that with your actual path to the jit debugger.  Should be in c:\program files\microsoft visual blah blah blah...

Answer (score 2):

Another neat trick that I learnt from reading "Programming Applications for Windows" by Jeffrey Richter

1. Create a DLL with a call to DebugBreak() in DLLMain() inside DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH case
2. Add path to your new DLL in the registry (it is a comma separated list):

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows\AppInit_DLLs
```

The image loader will create your process and load all DLLs entered in the registry. This will call DLLmain and your breakpoint will get hit.

Note: To avoid debugging all applications, check the process name with "GetModuleBasename" and call the break point only for processes you are interested.

Comment: Since it's a documented trick, it's likely to continue to work. But be aware that you'll hit that breakpoint holding the Loader Lock.